# What does needsRehash() return if the password repeats?

Tags: php, cakephp

To be more clear of my question does:

```
needsRehash($value)
```

return? true or 1?

Answer (score 1):

According to:

https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/Auth/DefaultPasswordHasher.php

cakephp's `needsRehash()` calls PHP's [password_needs_rehash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-needs-rehash.php) which:

> Returns TRUE if the hash should be rehashed to match the given algo and options, or FALSE otherwise.

Additional references:

https://api.cakephp.org/3.3/class-Cake.Auth.AbstractPasswordHasher.html#_needsRehash

https://api.cakephp.org/3.3/source-class-Cake.Auth.AbstractPasswordHasher.html#65-78